# Box Java SDK - 404 File Not Found on publicly available document

Tags: java, scala, access-token, box-api

I;m using Box SDK to get an access token like this:

```
val MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES = 100
val accessTokenCache: IAccessTokenCache = new InMemoryLRUAccessTokenCache(MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES)

val boxConfig: BoxConfig = {
    // Read Box config file
    val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream( path )
    val reader = new InputStreamReader( stream )
    BoxConfig.readFrom( reader )
}

val connection: BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(boxConfig, accessTokenCache)

val accessToken = connection.getAccessToken()
```

Then with this access token and the file ID I send POST to read the file as follows:

```
val fileId = "FILE ID"
val url = s"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/$fileId/content"
val header = List(Header("Authorization", s"Bearer $token"))
// send request
```

When I send the POST request with this auto generate token I get back a 404 File Not Found error, but if I manually generate a token from Box Developer Console the same code works and I can retrieve the file content.

Response looks like this

```
{
  "access_token":"TOKEN",
  "expires_in":4195,
  "restricted_to":[],
  "token_type":"bearer"
}
```

Am I using the access token wrong?

Comment: File ID is not encoded

Comment: what do you mean not encoded? the file id above is just a placeholder and with same file id and a developer token i'm able to read the file.

Comment: URL encoded ...

Comment: what do you mean url encoded??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to read the file using the shared link as follows:

```scala
    val enterpriseApi = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(boxConfig, accessTokenCache)

    // Read File Metadata
    val sharedLink = "......"
    val info = BoxItem.getSharedItem(enterpriseApi, sharedLink)

    println(s"File ID: ${info.getID}, Owener ID: ${info.getOwnedBy().getID} and name ${info.getOwnedBy().getName}")

    // Create a connection as the File owner
    val api = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(info.getOwnedBy().getID, boxConfig)
    println(s"enterprise token ${client.connection.getAccessToken}, user token is ${api.getAccessToken}")

    // Read file as user
    val file: BoxFile = new BoxFile(api, info.getID)
    val output = new ByteOutputStream()
    file.download(output)
    println(new String(output.getBytes))
```

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like you're using a JWT / OAuth 2 based app on Box, so when you get your access token (BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection) that access token is referencing your service account.

The service account is a programmatic Box account that represents your application - for all intents and purposes it is just another user account without login credentials for box.com.

My guess on why you're getting a 404 is that the file ID you're referencing is for a file that's stored in some other user account (quite possibly your own box.com account). Since the access token is scoped for the service account it's trying to find the file ID in that service account, not in your other account. By default a service account can't just access all files / folders owned by other folks in your company / enterprise, it can only access its own data unless it's collaborated in on the file / folder.

To access that file, you need to make a request as the user that owns the file. [Here's a guide](https://developer.box.com/docs/work-with-users#section-generate-a-user-access-token) on how to generate an access token that's scoped for the user, which should solve the problem.

Hope that helps,
Jon

Comment: that's correct, i did understand that the access token was a service account token. How can I get the user id if I just have a file ID?